# How to create an npm CLI package hosted on Gitlab

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, command-line-interface

My goals is to create a CLI script to install globally (`npm i -g @born05/cli`).

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@born05/cli",
  "version": "1.0.7",
  "description": "The Born05 handy-dandy development Command Line Interface",
  "main": "lib/cli.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "Niels Wijers",
    "email": ""
  },
  "bin": {
    "born05": "lib/cli.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "publishConfig": {
    "@born05:registry": "https://gitlab.born05.com/api/v4/projects/147/packages/npm/"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "deprecated": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "findit": "^2.0.0",
    "inquirer": "^7.3.3",
    "js-yaml": "^4.0.0",
    "tar": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

The script is created and tested locally and it works, even after `npm link` the script is working when typing `born05` in my terminal. But after publishing and installing it globally it fails to link the cli.js to the bin dir but the package is installed successfully.

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - publish

publish:
  stage: publish
  image: node:15.0-slim
  before_script:
    - npm install
    - |
      {
        echo "@born05:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/"
        echo "${CI_API_V4_URL#https?}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
      } | tee --append .npmrc
  script:
    - npm publish
```

My .npmrc

```
@born05:registry = "https://gitlab.born05.com/api/v4/packages/npm/" 
//gitlab.born05.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken = (protected)
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and my solution was to export the parameter manually:

```
    - npm install
    - |
      {
        echo "@born05:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/"
        echo "${CI_API_V4_URL#https?}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
      } | tee --append .npmrc
    - export NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/
```